# Universal Link, AASA file component syntax wrong

Tags: ios, syntax-error, ios-universal-links

I correctly have created Universal Link on iOS side and also successfully upload it to the domain.
Apple Validate service shows me that all work fine but I can't open specific links because the syntax of the component wrong
My file:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [ "K6789HNH.com.example-app" ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/#/market/lettings"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/#/market/lettings/*"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/#/market/acquisitions"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/#/market/acquisitions/*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "K6789HNH.com.example-app" ]
    }
}
```

Example of links:

```
https://example.com/#/market/lettings/49830?view=grid
https://example.com/#/market/acquisitions/50134
```

I follow the Apple example of components https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/717/ , time code 7:23 - 9:00
Image from example above[image]

What is my syntax problem with components?

Comment: You have to match on the fragment, not the path. `/market/listings` is  not a url path. It is a fragment value. Use something like `"#","/market/lettings"`

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, I'll try, how I can use empty components, it will work with this syntax example: "components":[]  ?

Comment: @Paulw11 how I can support all fragment ? I did use syntax "components": [
                    {
                        "#": "*fragment"
                    }
                ]

and it not work (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the symbol "#", it's a fragment, a little info about [URL](https://www.webdevsplanet.com/post/url-parameters-vs-fragments)
I change components to :

```
"#": "*market/lettings*"
```

and

```
"#": "*market/acquisitions*"
```

And all work well, symbol * used for handling all value between **#** and **market/**. Example: [www.example.com/#.......market/lettings](http://www.example.com/#.......market/lettings), instead of ... can be any of the symbols like *[www.example.com/#/market/lettings/123](http://www.example.com/#/market/lettings/123)*